# RAD tool for Mac OS X. Is there any?

Tags: macos, delphi

I wonder if there is any RAD tool for Mac OS X. Something like Delphi for Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Installing_Lazarus_on_MacOS_X) is an IDE for Free Pascal that works on Mac OS X (among other platforms). Obligatory screenshot [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Image%3aLazarus_Mac_OS_X.png).

Note: Lazarus supports two widget sets (Carbon and QT), with a third in Alpha (COCOA), most screenshots will be of the Carbon port nowadays.

Comment: Thanks Marco! I thought you'd have something to add to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Which languages are you interested in?

Certainly check out [Cocoa, XCode and Interface Builder](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html).

Comment: I'd like to add that with Cocoa and Xcode, one really should learn how to unleash the power of Interface Builder. Then a lot of programming does become pretty rapid :-)

Answer (score 4):

An actual Delphi for Windows that will allow you to cross compile your applications to Macintosh has been promised by Embarcadero (the current owners of Delphi).

The IDE will be a Windows product but the binaries it produces will run on a Mac.

It was due this year but wasn't ready for the September release of the latest Delphi. There are likely to be preview releases for existing Delphi customers in a few months from now but the actual product probably won't be released until around September 2011.

Comment: No, there won't be a Delphi for Mac. You can compile applications FOR hte Mac, but not ON the Mac with the new Delphi. If it ever comes out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make that clearer. You could of course run it on a Mac using a VM.

Comment: A VM + a Windows license you have to buy. Also it will use Qt, and not a native wrapper over Cocoa.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an update.

With Delphi XE-2, you can now build and compile native 32-bit Mac OS X programs.

Answer (score 0):

[Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism) XE is an add-on for Visual Studio that supports both .NET as Mono. This includes the MONO version used by the Mac. It's not the ideal solution and I haven't been able to check if it really works, since I don't have a Mac. But I have Prism and now my .NET environment allows me to write Delphi applications for the Mac. Again, too bad I don't have a Mac, else I would have been able to tell you how good that is!.
It appears as if the Delphi Prism IDE can also be installed as a stand-alone compiler with it's own IDE on a Mac. Again, I haven't tested this. I just know it has this option, since I saw it appear during installation.

As [Frank Shearar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10259/frank-shearar) already said, Lazarus is a Pascal IDE which would be a better solution for the Mac, right now.